# Update Apple ID Settings (iOS) - Enter Mac Password "Enter the Password you use to unlock the Mac" with correct password reports "Incorrect Password"

Tags: ios, mac, icloud, apple-id, password

On my iPhone (iOS 15.5), the Settings app displays a notification "Update Apple ID Settings".

[image: Notification "Update Apple ID Settings"]

When I open it, I get informed that "Some account services will not be available until you sign in again".

[image: "Some account services will not be available until you sign in again"]

When I tap to *Continue*, first I get requested to enter my Apple ID Password:

[image: Enter Apple ID Password]

Then I get requested to enter my iPhone Passcode:

[image: Enter iPhone Passcode]

Finally I get a prompt to enter my Mac Password:

[image: Enter Mac Password]

... and this is where the process seems to fail for me…

The dialog reports *Incorrect Password*, while I'm convinced that I entered my Mac password correctly. Yes, I already retried several times. I also tried with my previous Mac password, but it did not help.

[image: Enter Mac Password: Incorrect Password]

I do want the end-to-end encryption to continue working between my devices - how can I get rid of this nagging "Update Apple ID Settings" notification?

Comment: Note: It turned out iCloud was still using my penultimate Mac password for end-to-end encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the following procedure did the trick for me:

1. On my Mac (macOS 12.5), sign out of Apple ID, then sign in again.

   Note: This required entering my iPhone Passcode on my Mac.
2. Then, to confirm that the current Mac password is used for end-to-end encryption, sign out of Apple ID on my iPhone (while keeping a copy of data on this iPhone), and sign in again (while uploading and merging data on this iPhone with iCloud).

   Note: Curiously I didn't get asked for my current Mac password this time…